# Nhibernate map one column to two tables based on type

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to create nhiberante mapping for this sql structure (so base on CompanyType it links CompanyId to either CompanyTypeA or CompanyTypeB):

```
----
UserTable
----
Id (int)
CompanyId (int)
CompanyType (int)
...
----

----
CompanyTypeA
----
Id (int)
Name (varchar)
----

----
CompanyTypeB
----
Id (int)
Name (varchar)
----


 public class User
 {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }
 }
```

CompanyTypeA.Id and CompanyType.Id are unique with each other.

I am interested in c# code mapping not xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual ICompany Company { get; set; }
}

public interface ICompany
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class CompanyA : Entity, ICompany { }

public class CompanyB : Entity, ICompany { }

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(u => u.Id);

        ReferencesAny(u => u.Company)
            .IdentityType<int>()
            .EntityIdentifierColumn("CompanyId")
            .EntityTypeColumn("CompanyType")
            .AddMetaValue<CompanyA>("companyA")
            .AddMetaValue<CompanyB>("companyB");
    }
}
public class CompanyAMap : ClassMap<CompanyA>
{
    public CompanyAMap()
    {
        Id(u => u.Id);
    }
}
public class CompanyBMap : ClassMap<CompanyB>
{
    public CompanyBMap()
    {
        Id(u => u.Id);
    }
}
```